# Angular2 router: How to share a value from parent to child routes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular2-routing

In an Angular2 app (using the final 1.x release) I have a page with several tabs. The parent state `/samples/{id}` has a child route for each tab. E.g. `/samples/{id}/location` or `/samples/{id}/execution`.

The sample data is one big object that is sent in one request by the server API, containing the data for all the tabs. So I want to load it only once, when the parent route is activated (in the component code or maybe in a resolve), then read from it in all my tabs.

Is there a way to directly share an object from the parent component to the components of the children routes ? Sort of like the scope was inherited in Angular 1 ?

I know I can use a service to share the object, I am just curious if there is a built-in solution.

I also know it is possible to get route parameters from the parent route but it would not be very useful in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "built-in solution" actually is using a shared service.

There is also the option of using `@Input()` decorators, but in your case it is not applicable, since you are using routes as far as I can tell. That is only applicable in parent-child relationships, where the child is inside the parent component.

Another option would be using a `Route Data Resolver` which resolves data before activating a route, but since the data is already loaded, the shared service option is the most optimal solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks! Finally, I used a resolver in the parent route to load the data once. The data is kept in a simple cache inside the service. I can then I access the already loaded data synchronously in each child route component.